# Export tables from Postgresql to Excel using Python interface

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to develop a form in python using tkinter to export tables from postgresql to excel files.
or export the result of sql query to excel

Ps: i'm a python beginner

Comment: stackoverflow isn't a code-writing service. What _specific_ part of the problem are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 parts to the problem, (i) read the table from the database (you can use psycopg2 library for that) (ii) Write the table to to a csv file (which can be read in excel).

1) Read the table : https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg2_Tutorial

```
import psycopg2

conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname='foo' user='dbuser' password='mypass'")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""SELECT * from bar""")
rows = cur.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print "   ", row[1]
```

2) Write as CSV : https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

```
import csv
with open('mytable.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    cwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in rows:
        cwriter.writerow(row)
```